# Navigate to a new URL

Tags: angular

This is a small part of my `127.0.0.1:8000/app/admin` page:
[image]
When I click on `switch to update mode` button, function `update()` gets executed, and it displays a list of football matches. When I click on a match from this list the content of the web page changes but the url remains the same : `app/admin`.

To change the url params, I add the id of the match I clicked on as follows:

```
 update(id) {
    this.router.navigate(['admin'], { queryParams: { id: id } });
    // code ...
}
```

Now when I click on a match from the list, the url gets updated to `127.0.0.1:8000/app/admin?id=match_id` , But when I try to access this url from my browser directly I land on `app/admin` content so I'm incapable of accessing `127.0.0.1:8000/app/admin?id=match_id` directly

Comment: For future improvement you can use `id` as path param in router so the url will justify the path like `localhost:8000/app/admin/matchId/:id`, So only this url can always help you in future.

Comment: Add the entire code so that it will be easy to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried subscribing to the route params in ngOnInit and inspecting them? Like below

In demo.component.ts

```
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

 matchId: string;

 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {        
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
      this.matchId = params.matchId;
    });
    /* Other stuff*/
    //check this.matchId and process accordingly
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    //check this.matchId and process accordingly
  }
 }
```

And In app-routing.module.ts

```
 { path : 'admin/:matchId', component: DemoComponent },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) . I ended up doing something really similar : ```ngOnInit() { this.resetFormFields(); this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => { const match_Id = params['id']; if(matchId){ //some code this.update(matchId) } })}``` Also used path : 'admin?id=:matchId' as a path in app-routing.module.ts since I'm using queryParams. But your solution must work too I just think there is no need for the ngAfterViewInit, just check if (matchId) in ngOnInit()

Comment: Great. yes checking the matchId is optional in ngAfterViewInit()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
navigateToAdmin() {
    this.roouter.navigate(['app/admin', {id: this.matchId}]);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work! I've already tried both navigate and navigateByUrl

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in plunker?

Answer (score 0):

```
 update(id) {
    this.router.navigate(['/admin'], { queryParams: { id: id } });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything!

Comment: is URL getting changed or not.

Comment: It does as I said in my post! It goes from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/admin` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/admin?id=7` when I click on the match whom id is 7

Comment: Yes it goes to app/admin if you hit directly with "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/admin?id=7". You need to capture this id inside the component in  ngOnIt() and process to show the desired output.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your last comment? How so?