# Can access to my route but cannot match any routes when loading the app from the url

Tags: angular, router

I would like to create a second route which is a copy from the first one (same component) but where i can pass parameters.
When i access to this second router from my routerlink everything is working well but when i reload my app from this url then i have an "Error: Cannot match any routes."

Seems is because except the parameter the route is the same but i want to keep the same name

```
{
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard, AuthorizationGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthenticationGuard, AuthorizationGuard],
    data: {
      permissions: ['FRONT_END-access']
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'deals',
        component: DealsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Deals',
          sidebar: {
            text: 'Deals',
            icon: 'show_chart'
            // icon: 'pages'
          },
          permissions: ['DEALS-view']
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'tags',
        component: TagsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Tags',
          sidebar: {
            text: 'Tags',
            icon: 'show_chart'
            // icon: 'pages'
          },
          permissions: ['DEALS-view']
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'tags/:type',
        component: TagsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Tags',
          sidebar: {
            text: 'Tags',
            icon: 'show_chart'
            // icon: 'pages'
          },
          permissions: ['DEALS-view']
        }
      },
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'deals',
      }
    ]
  }
```

I can access to /tags/me without problem but when i load my app from it then i get the error
Do you have some suggestion pls ?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the route changes for the reload to work. Please look at the below to see if its the same thing that you are trying to achieve.

[Navigate to a new URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287254/navigate-to-a-new-url/57288940#57288940)

Comment: Well the problem is not to get the parameters of the route but just to access to the page cause when i reload '/tags/me' i get the error 'Cannot match any routes.'

Comment: I believe so. In your routes you have mentioned tags/:type but I cannot see you have subscribed to it unless you are doing it in TagsComponent. It would be nice if you can post what you are doing in TagsComponent to provide better assistance. See below link if it helps https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-6-url-parameters-860db789db85